# Display images in kendo grid column

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui

the grid do not display anything, this is the code in the javascript method

```
columns: [
        { field: "Dimension", title: "Mois",  width: "130px" },
        { field: "Value", title: "Variation CA", width: "130px"},
        { field: "Value", title: "", width: "30px", template: '# if (Value >= 0 ) { # <img src="~/Images/uparrow.jpg" /> # } else # { <img src="~/Images/downarrow.jpg" #}#' }
    ]
});
```

I can' fix the problem, the grid do not display anything, any suggestions please? how can i display imaes in the column using the if condition

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: There is at least an error in your template. # } else # { should be # } else { #. Could you post the complete grid code or reproduce in JSFiddle?