# Kendo grid image column

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

working on a MVC4 project, I'm trying to add a column to my kendo grid that displays an image.

```
<div id="datagrid">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SustIMS.Models.ConcessionModel>()
    .Name("datagrid_Concessions")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Code).Title(ViewBag.lblCode);
        columns.Bound(c => c.Description).Title(ViewBag.lblDescription);
        columns.Template(@<text>
                <img src='@item.Image' /> 
            </text>
            ).Title("Image");
    })
```

I've tried that but no luck. Also tried:

```
columns.Template(@<text>
         <img src='../../Images/pic.png' /> 
    </text>
    ).Title("Image");
```

The images aren't shown, whether I define the image `src` in the controller or write it directly in the view.

I've checked both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16400153/display-images-in-kendo-grid-column) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16037136/defining-custom-template-for-kendo-ui-grid-column) question but the images aren't displayed.

Can anyone help?

**EDIT**

Here's the Concession Model:

```
public class ConcessionModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Code { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string TrafficOpeningDate { get; set; }
        public string CreationDate { get; set; }
        public string CreationUser { get; set; }
        public string Image { get; set; }
        ...
```

The `Image` property is a string that contains something like "C:\whatever\pic.png"

Comment: What is the value of `@item.Image`?

Comment: @Brett, it's what I want: `../../Images/pic.png`, `/Images/pic.png`, `~/Images/pic.png`, ... I've tried a few possibilities

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try like this,

```
columns.Template(e => { }).ClientTemplate("<img src='../../Images/pic.png'/>").Width(140).Title("Image");
```

**DEMO:**

**View**

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Category>().Name("people")
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(m => m.Id);
        })
            .Read(read => read.Action("GetCategory", "Category"))
    )
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Id);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ImageUrl).ClientTemplate("<img src='" + Url.Content("~/CategoryImage/") + "#=ImageUrl#' alt='#=Name #' Title='#=Name #' height='62' width='62'/>");

    })
)
```

**Model**

```
public class Category
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        [UIHint("FileUpload")]
        [Required]
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public string FileName { get; set; }

        internal static object ToDataSourceResult(Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceRequest dsRequest)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
 public static List<Category> Category = new List<Category>();

        private int _nextid = 4;

        static CategoryController()
        {
            Category.Add(new Category { Id = 1, Name = "Desert", ImageUrl = "Desert.jpg" });
            Category.Add(new Category { Id = 2, Name = "Hydrangeas", ImageUrl = "Hydrangeas.jpg" });
            Category.Add(new Category { Id = 3, Name = "Tulips", ImageUrl = "Tulips.jpg" });
        }

        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewData["Category"] = Category;
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetCategory([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dsRequest)
        {
            var result = Category.ToDataSourceResult(dsRequest);
            return Json(result);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, I was testing your previous answer and both your answers work! However, now that I can show an image by writing the img src like `<img src='../../Images/pic.png'/>`, I want this `src`to be filled by the image `src` that exists in the model. How to bind that?

Comment: @chiapa please show your model so i understand.What exactly you want.

Comment: Jaimin, I just posted the model in my question

Comment: Thanks a lot Jaimin, it works now. At last I find someone who works with Kendo asp.Net MVC and understands it. I've been struggling with the kendo controls for a while, can you please see some of my questions ([this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24997246/kendo-grid-change-event-fires-only-once-per-row-selection) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883572/javascript-runtime-error-object-doesnt-support-property-or-method-in-interne)) that involve kendo that are still unanswered and I guess will remain that way...? Again, thanks a lot

Comment: @chiapa Welcome and i will look in to your question and let you know.

Comment: Hi Jaimin, what if the image `src` property is a server path? I'm having trouble with [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26176564/kendo-grid-column-with-image-from-a-server), can you please help?