# how to add image in kendo grid in mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hello Anyone can tell me how can i add image in kendo grid coloumn from database. Actually i am tring from morning but not succeed.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<TelerikMvcAppCombo.Models.ImageModel>()
.Name("grdImageModel")
.Columns(columns =>
{
    //columns.Bound(c => c.IMAGESIZE_ID).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' value =#IMAGESIZE_ID#  />").Width(50);
    columns.Bound(c => c.IMAGESIZE_ID).ClientTemplate("<input type='checkbox' value =#IMAGESIZE_ID#  />");
    columns.Bound(c => c.IMAGESIZE_NAME).Width(140);
    columns.Bound(c => c.IMAGESIZE_DESC).ClientTemplate("<img src=@Url.Content(~/Images/normal_234.png)");
    columns.Bound(c => c.created_by);
    columns.Bound(c => c.created_date);
    columns.Bound(c => c.modified_by);
    columns.Bound(c => c.modified_date);
})
.HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 580px;" })
.Scrollable()
.Groupable()
.Sortable()
.Pageable(pageable => pageable
    .Refresh(true)
    .PageSizes(true)
    .ButtonCount(10)
)
.DataSource(datasource => datasource
    .Ajax()
    .Read(read => read
            .Action("GetData", "Image")
          ))

)
```

Comment: try something like **columns.Template(e => { }).ClientTemplate("<img src='../../Images/pic.png'/>").Width(140).Title("Image");**

Comment: is not working @jbutler483

Comment: [See this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014428/kendo-grid-image-column)

Comment: Thanks but i already seen this

Comment: columns.Bound(c => c.IMAGESIZE_DESC).ClientTemplate("<img src='" + Url.Content("~") + "#IMAGESIZE_DESC#' alt='#=IMAGESIZE_NAME #' height='62' width='62'/>"); see my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it this way:

**HTML**

```
columns.Bound(u => u.Image).ClientTemplate("#=GetImage(data.Image)#").HtmlAttributes(new { style = "text-align: center; width: 30%; min-width: 60px;" });
```

**Javascript**

```
function GetImage(image) {
    var returnString = '<img src="~/Images/normal_234.png" title=\"image\" height=\"24\" alt=\"image\"/>';   
    return returnString;
}
```

Comment: can you tell me how get image at runtime

Comment: What do you mean @DurgpalSingh?

Comment: I am using kendogrid popup and i want to edit my template then how can i do that?

Comment: If you're using the kendo edit popup, you think you can't. You must create your own template and place a `<img>` tag with the `src` you want. What template are you using? Post your code

Comment: @DurgpalSingh, I have noticed in your profile that you have several questions asked but never marked any as accepted, even though you refer in comments that some answers worked for you: **you should mark all answers that work as answered** by clicking on the tick under the voting arrows. This way you reward the people who answered correctly with some reputation points and gain yourself 2 reputation points, only by marking the answer as accepted. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: @DurgpalSingh, you are confusing upvoting and marking as accepted: you **upvoted** the answer. When you click the up arrow, you upvote it; when you click the transparent checkmark (under the voting arrows), it becomes green and that means you mark the answer as correct -> this is what you should do for answers that you see as correct for your question

Comment: my question is right then you also marked as right question

Comment: I understand you asking for an upvote. Again, upvote and marking as right are two different things! Questions can't be marked as right, only answers can! Your question can be upvoted if the users that see it find it deserves upvoting (well built, helpful, clever)